# moved the css code to its own file using href="" (almost all symbols like < , : , and > are underlined red

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging

However when i move my css code back into the body in the html file (not using href="") the edits like padding, and color got applies to the frontend, here is my css code.

```
<style>
.subscribe-button {
background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
color:white;
border: none;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 16px;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 10px;
transition: opacity 0.15s;
vertical-align: top;}
</style>
```

Comment: What "bug" are you referring to?  Please clarify the specific problem you are observing.

Comment: almost all the symbols in my code are UNDERLINED red, and all the edits i made like the padding, color, font, are not applying to the frontend

Comment: Could you show us how EXACTLY your HTML and CSS files look like?

Comment: What specifically is "highlighting" your code?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  You need to describe the problem.

Comment: ok give me a moment... I meant underlined, im guessing that means a bug in VScode IDE

Comment: it appears the problem is with href="" if i move the css code to its own file would i leaveit as is? do i have to put it inside <body><body>

Comment: @codingbyDEC: At this point you've removed all code from the question and are just asking why some text somewhere is underlined red by something.  The answer below, while only a guess, is currently the best guess we can give you.  You've clearly *done something* (we don't know what) and encountered *some unexpected result* (we don't know what).  Based on what you've said so far, it seems likely that you're including HTML code in a CSS file.  CSS files are for CSS code.  HTML files are for HTML code.

Comment: @David its doesnt let me put the code it, it says it is formatted wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've accedentally copied css with html tags into your .css file.
Make sure that the only code you have in .css file is the code between  tags.

Style.css file contents should look like this.

```css
  .subscribe-button {
    background-color: rgb(204, 0, 0);
    color:white;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: opacity 0.15s;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .subscribe-button:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
  }
  .subscribe-button:active {
   opacity:0.4;
  }


  .join-button {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    border: 1px solid #065fd4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
  
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: background-color .15s,
      color .15s;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

    .join-button:active {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .join-button:hover {
    background-color: hwb(222 13% 3%);
    color:  rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
  

  .tweet-button 
  {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(29, 155, 240);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(3, 134, 216);
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15;
    transition: box-shadow .15s;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .tweet-button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.159);
   
  }
```

html file contents should look like this

```html
<button class="subscribe-button"> 
SUBSCRIBE
</button>

<button class="join-button">
JOIN
</button>

<button class="tweet-button">
Tweet
</button>
```

Comment: Its is now fully working, thanks it was basically only the html tags that created the issues?

Comment: Yes, .css file cannot contain html. Glad it solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you misunderstood how the .css file works. You shouldn't have any HTML tags in it (for example `<div>`). Here is how it should look like: https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-create-a-css-external-style-sheet/ Use only selectors `.div{}` and the code inside them `.div{color:red;}`.

Comment: thank you, im getting somewhere now, i removed the style tag and one elemnt of 3 is now working

Comment: @codingbyDEC What is it? Show us the code that is not working, put it between ``` (3` left - code - 3` right).